# Lua: Why can't I require a locally-installed package?

Tags: lua, torch, torchnet

I've created an OpenResty/Lusty project and have been trying to use it to wrap a REST API around a classifier that I'm using. Unfortunately, I haven't gotten much luck, and my root cause is that when I try to

```
require 'nn'
require 'image'
```

Lua fails to interpret the file. Unfortunately, Lusty doesn't give me a stack trace in the logs and simply returns a `404` error. However, after much code commenting and trial/error, I've determined the root cause is that an error is thrown when I try to require these packages.

I've installed OpenResty/Lusty using Luarocks on a Docker container that is pre-built with Torch7 and other utilities. When I try to run the classifier on its own, I can easily do so with `th classify.lua`. However, when I try to make it a Lusty request wrapped in its own function, the import above fails and Lusty returns with a `404` error, which I believe is actually a `500` error because if I comment out Torch code, it will return `200`.

It's important to note that I've used the `luarocks` command that came with the pre-built container. Additionally, when I check the local install folder I find the following packages, including `nn` and `image`:

[image: installed packages]

Here's the code I'm using on the implementation, any idea why I can't import these packages?

**package.path in classify.lua**

```
.\/app\/?.lua;\/opt\/openresty\/lualib\/?.lua;\/opt\/openresty\/lualib\/?\/init.lua;\/root\/.luarocks\/share\/lua\/5.1\/?.lua;\/root\/.luarocks\/share\/lua\/5.1\/?\/init.lua;\/root\/torch\/install\/share\/lua\/5.1\/?.lua;\/root\/torch\/install\/share\/lua\/5.1\/?\/init.lua;.\/?.lua;\/root\/torch\/install\/share\/luajit-2.1.0-beta1\/?.lua;\/usr\/local\/share\/lua\/5.1\/?.lua;\/usr\/local\/share\/lua\/5.1\/?\/init.lua;
```

**lusty_project/app/request/classify.lua**

```
-- these require statements throw an error
require 'nn'
require 'image'


function classifyImage()
  local ParamBank = require 'ParamBank'
  local label     = require 'classifier_label'
  torch.setdefaulttensortype('torch.FloatTensor')
  torch.setnumthreads(opt.threads)


  -- set modules to be in use
  if opt.backend == 'nn' or opt.backend == 'cunn' then
     require(opt.backend)
     SpatialConvolution = nn.SpatialConvolutionMM
     SpatialMaxPooling = nn.SpatialMaxPooling
     ReLU = nn.ReLU
     SpatialSoftMax = nn.SpatialSoftMax
  else
     assert(false, 'Unknown backend type')
  end


  local net = nn.Sequential()
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(3, 96, 7, 7, 2, 2))
     net:add(ReLU(opt.inplace))
     net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 3, 3))
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(96, 256, 7, 7, 1, 1))
     net:add(ReLU(opt.inplace))
     net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(256, 512, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
     net:add(ReLU(opt.inplace))
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(512, 512, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
     net:add(ReLU(opt.inplace))
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(512, 1024, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
     net:add(ReLU(opt.inplace))
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(1024, 1024, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
     net:add(ReLU(opt.inplace))
     net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 3, 3))
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(1024, 4096, 5, 5, 1, 1))
     net:add(ReLU(opt.inplace))
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(4096, 4096, 1, 1, 1, 1))
     net:add(ReLU(opt.inplace))
     net:add(SpatialConvolution(4096, 1000, 1, 1, 1, 1))
     if not opt.spatial then net:add(nn.View(1000)) end
     net:add(SpatialSoftMax())
     print(net)

     -- init file pointer
     print('==> overwrite network parameters with pre-trained weigts')
     ParamBank:init("net_weight_1")
     ParamBank:read(        0, {96,3,7,7},      net:get(1).weight)
     ParamBank:read(    14112, {96},            net:get(1).bias)
     ParamBank:read(    14208, {256,96,7,7},    net:get(4).weight)
     ParamBank:read(  1218432, {256},           net:get(4).bias)
     ParamBank:read(  1218688, {512,256,3,3},   net:get(7).weight)
     ParamBank:read(  2398336, {512},           net:get(7).bias)
     ParamBank:read(  2398848, {512,512,3,3},   net:get(9).weight)
     ParamBank:read(  4758144, {512},           net:get(9).bias)
     ParamBank:read(  4758656, {1024,512,3,3},  net:get(11).weight)
     ParamBank:read(  9477248, {1024},          net:get(11).bias)
     ParamBank:read(  9478272, {1024,1024,3,3}, net:get(13).weight)
     ParamBank:read( 18915456, {1024},          net:get(13).bias)
     ParamBank:read( 18916480, {4096,1024,5,5}, net:get(16).weight)
     ParamBank:read(123774080, {4096},          net:get(16).bias)
     ParamBank:read(123778176, {4096,4096,1,1}, net:get(18).weight)
     ParamBank:read(140555392, {4096},          net:get(18).bias)
     ParamBank:read(140559488, {1000,4096,1,1}, net:get(20).weight)
     ParamBank:read(144655488, {1000},          net:get(20).bias)
  -- close file pointer
  ParamBank:close()


  -- load and preprocess image
  print('==> prepare an input image')
  local img = image.load(opt.img):mul(255)

  -- use image larger than the eye size in spatial mode
  if not opt.spatial then
     local dim = (opt.network == 'small') and 231 or 221
     local img_scale = image.scale(img, '^'..dim)
     local h = math.ceil((img_scale:size(2) - dim)/2)
     local w = math.ceil((img_scale:size(3) - dim)/2)
     img = image.crop(img_scale, w, h, w + dim, h + dim):floor()
  end


  -- memcpy from system RAM to GPU RAM if cuda enabled
  if opt.backend == 'cunn' or opt.backend == 'cudnn' then
     net:cuda()
     img = img:cuda()
  end


  -- save bare network (before its buffer filled with temp results)
  print('==> save model to:', opt.save)
  torch.save(opt.save, net)


  -- feedforward network
  print('==> feed the input image')
  timer = torch.Timer()
  img:add(-118.380948):div(61.896913)
  local out = net:forward(img)


  -- find output class name in non-spatial mode
  local results = {}
  local topN = 10
  local probs, idxs = torch.topk(out, topN, 1, true)

  for i=1,topN do
     print(label[idxs[i]], probs[i])
     local r = {}
     r.label = label[idxs[i]]
     r.prob = probs[i]
     results[i] = r
  end

  return results
end

function errorHandler(error)
  return {message: "error"}
end

context.template = {
  type = "mustache",
  name = "app/templates/layout",

  partials = {
    content = "app/templates/classify",
  }
}


context.output = {
  message = xpcall(classifyImage, errorHandler)
}

context.response.status = 200
```

Thank you to anyone who can help. I'm a Lua n00b and not yet used to its packaging capabilities.

## Update

I've figured out how to finally return the error in the result, after realizing I can capture the error using `xpcall`'s second return variable (`local resultCode, error = xpcall(func, errHandler)`).

The error is this:

```
{"message":false,"errorMessage":"[string \".\/app\/requests\/classify.lua\"]:3: module 'nn' not found:\n\tno field package.preload['nn']\n\tno file '.\/app\/nn.lua'\n\tno file '\/opt\/openresty\/lualib\/nn.lua'\n\tno file '\/opt\/openresty\/lualib\/nn\/init.lua'\n\tno file '\/root\/.luarocks\/share\/lua\/5.1\/nn.lua'\n\tno file '\/root\/.luarocks\/share\/lua\/5.1\/nn\/init.lua'\n\tno file '\/root\/torch\/install\/share\/lua\/5.1\/nn.lua'\n\tno file '\/root\/torch\/install\/share\/lua\/5.1\/nn\/init.lua'\n\tno file '.\/nn.lua'\n\tno file '\/root\/torch\/install\/share\/luajit-2.1.0-beta1\/nn.lua'\n\tno file '\/usr\/local\/share\/lua\/5.1\/nn.lua'\n\tno file '\/usr\/local\/share\/lua\/5.1\/nn\/init.lua'\n\tno file '\/opt\/openresty\/lualib\/nn.so'\n\tno file '\/root\/torch\/install\/lib\/nn.so'\n\tno file '\/root\/.luarocks\/lib\/lua\/5.1\/nn.so'\n\tno file '\/root\/torch\/install\/lib\/lua\/5.1\/nn.so'\n\tno file '.\/nn.so'\n\tno file '\/usr\/local\/lib\/lua\/5.1\/nn.so'\n\tno file '\/usr\/local\/lib\/lua\/5.1\/loadall.so'"}

[string "./app/requests/classify.lua"]:5: module 'nn' not found:
    no field package.preload['nn']
    no file './app/nn.lua'
    no file '/opt/openresty/lualib/nn.lua'
    no file '/opt/openresty/lualib/nn/init.lua'
    no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/nn.lua'
    no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/nn/init.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/init.lua'
    no file './nn.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/nn.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nn.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nn/init.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/extra/nn/nn.lua'
    no file '/opt/openresty/lualib/nn.lua'
    no file '/opt/openresty/lualib/nn/init.lua'
    no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/nn.lua'
    no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/nn/init.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/init.lua'
    no file './nn.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/nn.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nn.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nn/init.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/extra/image/nn.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/extra/nn/nn.lua'
    no file '/opt/openresty/lualib/nn.so'
    no file '/root/torch/install/lib/nn.so'
    no file '/root/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/nn.so'
    no file '/root/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/nn.so'
    no file './nn.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nn.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

And when I do a search for `nn` via `find -name nn` I get:

```
./root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn
./root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nngraph
./root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nnx
./root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/nn
./root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/nn/scm-1/nn-scm-1.rockspec
./root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/nngraph
./root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/nngraph/scm-1/nngraph-scm-1.rockspec
./root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/nnx
./root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/nnx/0.1-1/nnx-0.1-1.rockspec
./root/torch/extra/nngraph
./root/torch/extra/nngraph/nngraph-scm-1.rockspec
./root/torch/extra/nnx
./root/torch/extra/nnx/build/CMakeFiles/nnx.dir
./root/torch/extra/nnx/nnx-0.1-1.rockspec
./root/torch/extra/nn
./root/torch/extra/nn/rocks/nn-scm-1.rockspec
./root/torch/.git/modules/extra/nngraph
./root/torch/.git/modules/extra/nnx
./root/torch/.git/modules/extra/nn
./usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/nn_index.h
./usr/share/locale/nn
./usr/share/i18n/locales/nn_NO
./usr/share/perl/5.18.2/Unicode/Collate/Locale/nn.pl
./usr/lib/python3.4/nntplib.py
./usr/lib/python2.7/nntplib.pyc
./usr/lib/python2.7/nntplib.py
```

Comment: I should add here that I've tried modifying the `package.path` at the top of `classify.lua`, however it doesn't try to check that file in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to resolve this problem. This is a rather complex permissions issue, since the nginx default is to run its worker process as the user `nobody`. Since OpenResty is tied to this particular worker process, all child Lua processes are also bound to that same user.

The simplest solution is to change permissions of all related files to the same user. So you could do something like:

```
chown -R nobody:nogroup openresty_project/
chmod -R 755 openresty_project/
```

Once doing so, you'll regain access to Luarocks that have been previously installed.

Note that you'll have to find all related lua directories and change the default user as well.

You also have another option to change the user in the nginx config, which can be done like this in `nginx.conf`:

```
user myuser mygroup;
```

Note that running as root is extremely dangerous and not recommended.